# School assignment (related to string manipulation)

Tags: java, string

**The question:** Write a sentence with at least eight words and assign it to a variable. This will be the text your program works on.

Create a string with every letter that appears at least twice in the sentence. The letters should be in the order of their first appearance in the sentence. Each letter can appear only once in the string. All letters should be in lowercase.

Print the original sentence to the screen, and then the string of letters.

Example:

- Input: Democracy is the worst form of government, except for all the others.
- Output: emocrasthfnl

**My attempt:**

```
private static String repeatedLetter(String sentence){
    String repeatedLetters = "";
    
    for(int i = 0; i < sentence.length(); i ++){
        char curI = Character.toLowerCase(sentence.charAt(i));
        
        for(int a = i + 1; a < sentence.length(); a ++){
            char curA = Character.toLowerCase(sentence.charAt(a));
            
            for(int b = 0; b < repeatedLetters.length(); b ++){
                char curB = repeatedLetters.charAt(b);
                
                if(Character.isLetter(curI) && curI == curA && curI != curB){
                    repeatedLetters += Character.toString(curI);
                    break;
                }
                else{
                    repeatedLetters += "";
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    return repeatedLetters;
}
```

**some problem with my code:** it is not returning anything, or the returned String is huge. I think my approach to this question is correct, but please correct me if I'm wrong and please help me with my implementation. Thank you very much!!!

**Thank you guys for the answers!!!**
**my new attempt: **

```
public String repeatedLetter(String sentence)
{
    System.out.println(sentence);
    String repeatedLetters = "";
    
    sentence = sentence.toLowerCase();
    sentence =sentence.replace(" ","");
    
    while(sentence.length() > 0)
    { 
        if(sentence.lastIndexOf(sentence.charAt(0))!= 0)
        {
            repeatedLetters += sentence.charAt(0);
        }
        
        sentence = sentence.replace("" + sentence.charAt(0), "");
    }
    return repeatedLetters;
}
```

}
**learned about lastIndexOf(), it worked!**

Comment: Then it's time to first do some debugging: ignore the original example phrase, and start small. Turn on the debugger, set your start phrase to "abc", step through your code, and verify that it does the right thing. Then set your phrase to "aba", step through your code again, and see if it does the right thing. At this point, you've almost certainly already found at least one thing you need to fix. Debugging tools there to help you find problems, not just there for professionals =)

Comment: Create a string with every letter that appears at least twice in the sentence. - count letters (put it in a Map<Char, Integer>, then filter only those which have at least 2 apperances. The letters should be in the order of their first appearance in the sentence. - You can use LinkedHashMap. Each letter can appear only once in the string. - I think you can use Set for it, or earlier filter to non-duplicates. All letters should be in lowercase. - String.toLowerCase() on final string.

Comment: Your program never gets into the "b loop" - you create a new string `String repeatedLetters = "";` - then in your "for" definition b is 0 `int b = 0` - and you compare b to the empty string you just created `b < repeatedLetters.length()`, which always begins at lenght 0

Comment: It would have helped had you given a true [mre]. The code you show should be able to be copied and pasted into an ide so that we can test it. This means, in Java, you need to have the correct import statements and a public static void main(String[] args) method. Rather than using keyboard import, you should define your input as a string (at least that part of it you seem to have done).

Answer (score 1):

Having so many for-loops inside of each other isn't a great idea maybe you should split this in two parts. First determining which letters are 2 times or more in the string. You could use this code snippet to store that information in a Map:

```
String myString = "Democracy is the worst form of government, except for all the other";
HashMap<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    
myString.chars()//Counts the chars
.forEach(Char -> map.put(Char, (map.containsKey(Char) ? map.get(Char) : 0) + 1));
map.entrySet().removeIf(entry -> entry.getValue() < 2);//Removes every char with an amount below 2
```

After that you can simply loop over your original String, determining the position of each char:

```
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
myString.chars().distinct().//Distinct will remove duplicate chars
filter(map::containsKey).forEach(charAsInteger -> sb.append((char)charAsInteger));
System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

Comment: I like this answer but you need to remove the space in the final string. Maybe with `sb.toString().replace(" ", "")`

Answer (score 0):

There are good followups on how to detect an error in the comments. Some of the answers give explicit solutions, so I'll try to guide you to finding a solution yourself. As randmon points out, your "b loop" never actually begins because b = 0 and repeatedLetters.length is also 0 at the beginning since it is an empty string. Note also that even if the loop started, the line `char curB = repeatedLetters.charAt(b)` will fail since the empty string "" does not have a 0th character.

As for your implementation, if I understand correctly, the outer "curI" loop is going through each character, the "curA" loop goes through every character afterwards, and the "curB" loop checks whether the character has already been included in `repeatedLetters`. This approach, broadly, is fine, but there are much more efficient ways of going about it than doing the triple-nested loop above.

I'll point you towards the following String methods that can help you simplify parts of your code:

contains(String find): This method will return true/false based on whether or not the string provided is inside of it. So, for example, if you want to check if a certain character is inside of `repeatedLetters`, you could do `repeatedLetters.contains(c + "")` where `c` is a character (the reason I add the quotes is to make the character into a String).

substring(int start): This method will return a subpart of a string. So, if I wanted to get all parts of a string named Cat after the 3rd character, I could do `Cat.substring(4)` (you have to do 4 instead of 3 since Substring includes the starting index). This, along with `contains`, can help you check if the remaining string after a certain point contains duplicates of any character.

Try reattempting your code with these functions and see if this simplifies the implementation. For reference I was able to write a working implementation with one for-loop with these functions (basically iterating over each character one-by-one). Best of luck!

Answer (score -2):

I wrote this for learning purpose, you can use it if you want:

```
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class LetterCounter {

    private final static String sentence = "Democracy is the worst form of government, except for all the others.";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(repeatedLetter(sentence));
    }

    private static String repeatedLetter(String sentence) {

        //remove spaces and etc., make it lowercase
        sentence = sentence.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z]", "").toLowerCase();

        //linked hash map to order elements by entry
        Map<Character, Long> lettersWithFrequency = new LinkedHashMap<>();

        //stream to count and put characters to map
        Stream.of(sentence)
                .flatMapToInt(CharSequence::chars)
                .mapToObj(c -> (char) c)
                .forEach(
                character -> {
                    lettersWithFrequency.putIfAbsent(character, 0L);
                    lettersWithFrequency.put(character, lettersWithFrequency.get(character) + 1);
                }
        );

        //print map if you want to check frequency for all letters
        System.out.println(lettersWithFrequency);

        //filter only for those which have at least 2 occurrences
        return lettersWithFrequency.keySet().stream()
                .filter(c -> lettersWithFrequency.get(c) >= 2)
                .map(Object::toString)
                .collect(Collectors.joining());
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a code-dump answer, and while it might help the original poster, it will in no way help future visitors with similar problems which is the entire purpose of this site. Please read the [answer] link to help improve your answers and this site